# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import - getting error while taking the build in Angular15 and also using Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass, kendo-ui

Getting below error after updated to angular15, and also using Kendo UI for the ui controls.
It seems that due to the tilde key depreciated.

```
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
3 │ @import "~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/grid/_index.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\assets\kendo-theme\kendo-imports.scss 3:9  @import
  src\styles.scss 3:9                            root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
3 │ @import "~@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/grid/_index.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\assets\kendo-theme\kendo-imports.scss 3:9  @import
  src\styles.scss 3:9                            root stylesheet
```

I tried to remove the tilde key (~) but there are many tildes reference in the node_module libraries for Kendo UI

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add the load-path option when running the sass command like so:

```
sass --load-path=node_modules --style compressed ./wwwroot/css/index.scss ./wwwroot/css/output.css
```

This lets Dart Sass know to look in the node_modules directory anytime the folder is not specified by an @import call.

Answer (score -1):

Change import line to: `@import "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/scss/grid/_index.scss";`

Comment: I have changed it but then I got below error.. seems like "~" need to remove from node_module folder, which is not practical..
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
3 │ @import "~@progress/kendo-theme-core/scss/functions/index.import.scss";
  │

Comment: Try to import from dist folder `@import 'node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap/dist/all.scss'`;

Comment: @AharonZaltz Isn't it the whole point: to not include all.scss but partials?